# How can I get Category of video in YouTube Data API V3?

Tags: python-3.x, youtube-data-api

I wanted to get some categories of video. But I can't find docs for it.

I'm getting the videos ID and title like this:

```py
resp = requests.get('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search', 
                    params= {
                        "key":"My Key",
                        "part":"snippet",
                        "q":"IT",
                        "maxResults":1,
                        "order":"rating",
                        "regionCode":"KR"
                        }
```

I found about it for 2 hours but can't find.
Sorry for my poor English. It takes long time to get used to English

Answer (score 0):

You have to make another request to the [videos:list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) endpoint to get the video details.

Here is an [example](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list?apix_params=%7B%22part%22%3A%5B%22id%2Csnippet%2CcontentDetails%2Cstatistics%2Cstatus%2CtopicDetails%22%5D%2C%22id%22%3A%5B%22ouf0ozwnU84%22%5D%7D).

Results of the sample - *simplified*:

```
"items": [
    {
      "kind": "youtube#video",
      "etag": "RL6[...]",
      "id": "ouf0ozwnU84",
      "snippet": {
        "publishedAt": "2022-02-25T23:00:16Z",
        "channelId": "UCYzHwra_yDr-QGFiopiOPnw",
        "title": "Cards to Consider: Blindly Loyal Goblin [...]",
        "description": "#Shorts\nWhy is Blindly Loyal Goblin Interesting?[...].",
        "thumbnails": {
          "default": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/ouf0ozwnU84/default.jpg"
          }
        },
        "channelTitle": "TCGTheory",
        "tags": [
          "TCGTheory",
          "Card Game Analysis",
          "Yu-gi-oh!",
          [...]
        ],
        "categoryId": "20", // <= Video category "Gaming".
      }
    }
]
```

In this example, the `categoryId` is 20 - Gaming.

You can check the video categories [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videoCategories/list).