# How do I get the video category associated with a youtube video from the video url?

Tags: api, youtube, youtube-api

I'm wokring on a personal project where I need to get the video category associated with a youtube video from the video url but I can't seem to find a solution. The Youtube API gives me a list of video categories but not assocaited with any specific video.

My code is basically scratched.

Comment: Please see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74306504/12511801) for guidance.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.